# Applet not working when acessed in local network

Tags: java, applet

I have an signed applet on a local page. Whenever you access the page locally the applet loads and runs correctly on chrome, firefox and IE. When you access by another machine on the LAN the applet still works perfectly in chrome and firefox. In IE 9, 10 displays only a white screen. Somebody has any idea what might be happening?

I have tried to reduce all levels of IE security with no success.

Applet Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is Java enabled on IE9 browser on that machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of Java not loading or not working in IE9 is because the Java applets has been blocked or filtered by ActiveX Filtering.

How to enable / disable ActiveX Filtering in IE9 is fully described [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-or-enable-turn-off-or-on-activex-filtering-in-ie9/).